# Multi-Background Images scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, image, background

I believe this effect can be created within the CSS, but I am not sure there might be some Javascript behind it. But basically I am trying to duplicate the background effect as seen on [meandmyaaa.com](http://meandmyaaa.com). As you scroll down the white circles behind the main image seem to scroll at different rates, how can this be achieved?

Comment: If you look at the source of the page you mentioned, the logic for the background is the last block of javascript you'll see. And if you want the same effect, this is exactly how you would do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually 3 backgrounds:

- `.contentContainer` holds the main background image and scrolls with the page as any background normally would
- `.bgCircle1` holds a background image of one set of circles
- `.bgCircle2` holds a background image of another set of circles

When you scroll the screen, `.contentContainer` scrolls normally whereas the scroll amount for `.bgCircle1` and `.bgCircle2` are calculated using this function which is bound to the scroll event of the window:

```
var offset = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
$('.bgCircle1').css({
  'backgroundPosition': 'center -' + (offset / px_scroll_amt) + 'px'
});
if (xhr_support) {
  $(".bgCircle2").css({
    'backgroundPosition': 'center -' + (offset / (px_scroll_amt / 3)) + 'px'
  });
}
```

It basically checks how far the window has scrolled and moves each of the backgrounds a different amounts. The background sizes are different heights to accommodate for this.